# how to show multiple type pending post under one menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have created 4 custom type posts news, article, technical and trading where author can submit the post for review.
On Submit the post will be submited for the admin to review and the status of post is put for is "pending".

I want a functionality where user can view all these custom type "pending" posts under one menu in the wordpress admin panel

how can I do it?

Comment: mean you want to one more menu on admin side, Which displayed all the pending post right ?

Comment: yes.. all the pending posts from all types of post at one place

Comment: If pending are shows are after custom post name then it's fine?
Like your-custom-postytpe-4,your-custom-postytpe-10,your-custom-postytpe-7,
digit mention the pending posts

Comment: no Dhruv this I have already done but I need a Separate section where Admin can view All Types pending posts

Comment: ohh it's custom level developing you need to made your own code.